# paypal access token issue

Tags: flask, paypal

Paypal access token expired after 24 or 48 hours, i want to update it when i get "401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url" on this response, the function which return an access token is working fine, here is my current approach which i have used to update the token if it expired but somehow it is not updating the access token and i am getting the same error "401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url", what can be the possible issue for it

```
def get_result_from_paypal(url):
    for attempt in range(10):
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, headers=paypal_headers)
            response.raise_for_status() 
            if response.status_code == 200:
                result = response.json()
                return result
            else:
                paypal_headers['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {paypal_token(paypal_client_id, paypal_client_secret, paypal_api_url)}'
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error fetching data from PayPal API: {e}")
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: instead of updating paypal token in else, you should do in except case, it will work